# How do I set the date to the next weekday of my choice using c++?

Tags: c++, windows, datetime, mfc

I would like to determine the next date that has a day of the week value equal to something I specify.

For example, today is 6/21/2010 and the day of week value is 1 b/c today is a Monday. How do I find the next date with let's say a day of week value of 3.

I would like to consider all cases that come close to the end of something including month and year.

Is there any easy way to do this or do I have to manually check to see if it's close to the end of the month or year and make adjustments accordingly? I feel there is an easily and better solution than doing that.

Comment: Are you using .Net, STL, or Boost?

Comment: It's just an MFC application, no STL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stuff your values into a `struct tm`, and then normalize them with a call to `mktime`. This will ignore the day of week and day of year on input, and normalize the other values. For example, you can feed it an input of February 31<sup>st</sup>, and it'll convert that to March 3<sup>rd</sup> (or March 2<sup>nd</sup> for a leap year).

To use this, the normal sequence would be to call `time` to get the current time as a time_t. Then convert that to a `struct tm` with a call to `localtime`. Adjust the time in the `struct tm` as needed (e.g., if it says today is Tuesday, and you want Friday, add three to the day of the month). Then call `mktime` to normalize the values, in case you've (for example) overflowed from one week/month/year to the next.